# How can I resolve the error during starting Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jdbc, tomcat7

I am trying to run Tomcat with `web-matrix.war`, but I can not.

I am look at log file and see exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while
>   extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC
>   driver of class '' for connect URL 'null' at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)

..............................................

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:524) at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:493) at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:262) at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)

My settings are:

```
/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/conf/Catalina/localhost/web-matrix.xml

<Context path="/web-matrix" reloadable="true">
<Resource
name="jdbc/webmatrix"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
username="webmatrix"
password="webmatrix"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@spb-fusion02:1521:orcl"
/>
</Context>
```

Does anyone help me?

I've checked the connection with listener. It's good.

[root@spb-fusionwm02 localhost]# /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/tnsping spb-fusionwm02:1521/orcl

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on 30-SEP-2014 09:22:17

Copyright (c) 1997, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora

Used EZCONNECT adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.82.64)(PORT=1521)))
OK (10 msec)

Comment: what is `spb-fusion02` in url ?

Comment: What was the solution? I suspect a missing classpath-ish dependency, like the OracleDriver that was mentioned?

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631494/cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-for-connect-url-null-oracle-xe-mvc-sprin

Answer (score 0):

in `driverClassNamee` try :

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;
```

I think the `url` you are passing to it is not proper so that's why you are getting problem.

where's the `oracle DB server` reside ?

On your machine or other ?

The error shows that the `source / url` is `null`.

Comment: thanks for answer. oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver - the same error.

Comment: I have written about trying to db connection.

Comment: How can I check db connection? I've written my trying in question, but it doesn't work.